# How to create a custom order like page [blocks] in magento adminhtml?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have created admin forms till now. And I am very new to magento and looking to create new blocks and section just like existing order page in magento for my custom module. My custom module also has a order page to order product from the product list and just like below I need the sections and blocks.

[image]

I have tracked the layout files and phtml files, but I am not aware how to call all of them that when is it possible to call an phtml file while clicking a button in previous page.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to manage your layout file. Inside this you have add this :

```
    <adminhtml_order_create>
    <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="ordercreate"    template="namespace/module/createorder.phtml" />                 
     </reference>       
     </adminhtml_order_create>
```

adminhtml:since this will in the admin panel
order: controller name
create: action name

Make sure you have the phtml file